# When is $\theta_{1}=-\theta_{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I chanced upon this expression in a physics text.

> $\sin\theta_{1}-\sin\theta_{2}$

[image]
[image]
It is claimed that $\theta_{1}=-\theta_{2}$ but under what circumstances does this generally holds truism?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $\sin \theta_1 = -\sin \theta_2$?

Comment: No. But I suspect they might have written it informally. These came from notes.
Pre algebra was a long time ago. Let's take it as $\sin\theta_{1}=-\sin\theta_{2}$

Comment: One possibility is they hid a use of the small-angle approximation. (This wouldn't be, strictly speaking, equality, but sometimes the approximation $\sin(x)=x$ is used in various physics texts, which is accurate to within about 1% for $-\pi/13\leq x\leq \pi/13$.)

That said, did they work with anything else, or is it just the drawing and that claim?

Comment: There are 'much' more as have been edited in the OP. But those additional information are hardly relevant.@NicholasStull